# How does spark load input file that is bigger than disk size of cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I am very new to Spark. I am bit confused about the way spark loads input data. For example: let’s say I have a 1 TB file and I have a spark cluster with 3 nodes (4cpu, 8gb ram and 10gb disk space) each. Now how does spark divide data among these nodes? Does it load just the metadata of file or it tries to load enough to fit in the cluster and process the file in iterations?

Answer (score -2):

File is stored in HDFS and not spark.
With replication factor 3 You will need 3 TB of Hardisk.

> Please follow the link for better understanding
>   http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/understanding-spark-through-map-reduce/

Comment: Thanks I will go through that link. Also when u said I need 3TB disk u means in spark cluster or hdfs/s3? If u meant hdfs/s3 that means spark loads data in chunks?

Comment: Please read about how InputFormats works, spark always read data in chunks. Only if you instruct to lad the whole data in memory it holds it there, else always its disk and memory

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/how-records-are-handled-map-reduce/

Comment: Thanks for the link once again but to be honest they don’t answer my question. But I guess I need to simplify my question. I understand that spark process data in chunks. But does it **download** block of data required to do computation from network (example: s3 bucket) or does it download entire file and then select which block should go to which node? So for your example do I need 3 TB disk space in my spark cluster?

Comment: Basically what happens under the hood for this line:

val myRdd = sc.textFile("s3n://myBucket/myFile1.log")

Comment: You answe a question to me , How do a normal Java program reads data from local file System, in chunks  or reads it completely in one go. 

1. S3, HDFS are filesystem like ext3. 
2. It will never download the file, it will read in small chunks.
3. S3 is a remote FileSystem, in this case there is no data Locality. 
4. Please  go through the basics, else all concepts will look very complicated

Comment: well u can download whole file from s3 before u process right? Why is it frustrating when people ask basic questions? I mean seriously how can you get an answer on stackoverflow without someone suggesting u to go through basics! I love how  people think after learning something that it should be very obvious to everyone! Anyways thanks for your answer!

Comment: You have mistaken my words, apologies for that. What i meant from basics was understanding the MR paradigm first before jumping onto spark, as most of the IO concepts from MR. 

http://bytepadding.com/map-reduce/
http://bytepadding.com/spark/

Elaborating on your answer. 
1. How can you downlaod a 1 TB file on 10 * 3 GB hardisk 
2. I am still learning not a master myself, apologies once again